# Can I interpret coefficients for "Year" as differences between years that are not explained by my predictors?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, splines, regression-strategies

I am doing statistical analysis of a natural experiment that consists of multiple years of measurements. I have two independent variables that are physically related to `Y`.

1. I am interested in whether there are differences between years that are not explained by the model.
2. I want to test whether a third predictor can reduce the differences between years.

I added `Year` as a categorial predictor in my linear regression (I am using natural cubic splines). My model looks like this:

```
Linear Regression Model

 ols(formula = depend ~ rcs(X1, 3) + rcs(X2, 4) + Yearf, data = data,
     x = T, y = T)

                 Model Likelihood    Discrimination
                       Ratio Test           Indexes
 Obs     869    LR chi2    805.76    R2       0.604
 sigma0.6327    d.f.           10    R2 adj   0.600
 d.f.    858    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    g        0.848

 Residuals

      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
 -2.75550 -0.40733  0.01893  0.42597  1.70108


            Coef    S.E.   t      Pr(>|t|)
 Intercept   1.5327 0.2067   7.41 <0.0001
 X1          1.0437 0.0525  19.89 <0.0001
 X1'        -0.8147 0.0686 -11.88 <0.0001
 X2          1.2507 0.1670   7.49 <0.0001
 X2'        -2.4775 0.6915  -3.58 0.0004
 X2''        3.2983 1.2123   2.72 0.0066
 Yearf=2016  0.2475 0.0814   3.04 0.0024
 Yearf=2017  0.1620 0.0802   2.02 0.0437
 Yearf=2018  0.0440 0.0862   0.51 0.6096
 Yearf=2019 -0.5260 0.0829  -6.34 <0.0001
 Yearf=2020  0.1457 0.0813   1.79 0.0734
```

Effect plots for the predictors look like this:

[image]

After adding X3, the effect plot looks like this:

[image]

Regarding my questions formulated at the beginning of this post, I would interpret the results as follows, but I am not sure if the whole approach is valid:

1. If `X1,X2` (and `X3` in the second plot) are set to their average values, the mean response of Y for each year would be the value within the plot for `Yearf`.
2. Visually it appears that the differences between the years reduces when `X3` is added to the model while the standard error of the mean response increases. Is it valid to do this visually? As far as I know, an `anova` only tells me if the difference between year x and my base year (here 2015) is significant, but I don’t want to compare it for a specific year. I want to get an idea of the whole picture. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well done.  I think your interpretation is OK.  Running `anova()` will give you a more general test for a time trend than how you described it---a test of whether the time trend is flat, i.e., where there is a difference between *any* pair of years.  It would also be useful to examine the difference in $R^2$ due to `yearf` with and without adjustment for `x3`.

The analysis would be slightly better were you to measure time with more resolution.  Then you could model year + fraction of a year instead of integer year.

Comment: Thank you!! Using ```validate``` I get the following corrected R2: ```X1,X2 = 0.5377``` ```X1,X2,Yearf = 0.5932```  ```X1,X2,X3 = 0.6039``` ```X1,X2,X3,Yearf = 0.6201``` I'd conclude from this that ```X3``` cannot explain all but some of the differences between the years. I have data with resolution of 30min-1 so I could go into a lot of more time-dependent details, but I also want to keep my readers interested. ;-)